# Python Library (foundation\FormParameters.py) error

Tags: python

The first line i enter in IDLE is

```
from foundation import FormParameters
```

And i get a error like this

```
>>> from foundation import FormParameters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from foundation import FormParameters
  File "C:\Python32\lib\foundation\FormParameters.py", line 19
    con_str = StringIO()
                       ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

As it is a standard library can i change it? or is there any other way round??

Comment: This isn't part of the standard library. Where did you get it?

Comment: Show us the part of code which has this line 19 in FormParemeters.py

Comment: @DanielRoseman  I got it from : [link](http://oneapi.gsma.com/developing-with-oneapi-in-python/) and the 19th line is
    def encodeParameters(self):
        from cStringIO import StringIO
        con_str = StringIO()"""19th line"""
        first=True

Comment: Here is the link for the api : [link](http://oneapi.gsmworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/oneapi-python.zip) size approx 120kb

Comment: You are using python 3.2. It runs well on my python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As it is a standard library can i change it?

You can just open the referenced File ("C:\Python32\lib\foundation\FormParameters.py") and edit it - in this case I would suggest replacing tabs with spaces, as tabs and python are an evil combination.

As some others commented, this is NOT a part of the standard library - but even if it were, the same rules would apply - find the file and you're free to edit it (you probably shouldn't though if you intend to run your programs on other machines with an unmodified standard library). For C extensions this pörocess is somewhat more complicated as you would need to compile them.